# Regex to match last element and the first element of a new line

Tags: regex

I have a json output as below : I need to remove comma (,) after Interface and UI tag. So on I need to have remove (,) from all the tags if its following line is } or ].

```
"DEVICERENDEROPTIONS": 
    [
    {
        "INTERFACE": "3",
    },
    {
        "UI": "[1,2,3,4]",
    }
    ],
```

Comment: Voted to close. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Why not just generate valid json to start with?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will do the trick.

```
var jsonString = JSON.strigify(json);
jsonString..replace(/,(\s+|)(\}|\])/g, '$2');
```